# Contacting Stack Overflow team

Tags: support, contact

About two months ago, I tried to contact the Stack Overflow team using the email address provided on the Contact Us page.  I have not heard back. Is there an alternate contact address?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`team@stackoverflow.com` is the correct address to use, but you can now also use [the new contact forms directly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact). Any of those methods should reach the SE team.

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively, you can mail SO using the form [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/other)
From the FAQs,

Advertising inquiries should be sent to

```
ads@stackexchange.com or call +1 (212) 232-8280.
```

For career related queries,

```
careers@stackoverflow.com
Phone    US: +1-212-232-8294 (9am - 5pm US Eastern Time)
UK: +44 (0)20 3239 9585 (0900 - 1700 GMT)
Office  55 Broadway, 26th Floor
New York, NY 10006
```