# How do I appeal a suspension on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, account-suspension, ban

I have been a user for about two months. I was recently suspended for one month.

The reason given for the suspension was inappropriate comments, but I disagree with this. I have been trying my best to help out and answer questions, and I believe I can make a case to have the suspension lifted.

Can I appeal this suspension and, if so, how do I do it?

Comment: Maybe if you weren't so insulting toward the mod and were a little cooler-headed it would help. Right now, I have a difficult time believing that was the *only* issue. You may not like what they did but they're still in a position of authority and deserve some respect.

Comment: The ban message says that you are suspended to 'cool down', and 1 month suggests that you have been suspended before.

Comment: You obviously didn't do your reading.. Reputation and badges are restored at the end of your suspension. And if you're always this insulting I'm not surprised you ended up suspended. Moderators don't suspend people for little things they did once.

Comment: Im obviously upset. Ask all the people ive helped im usually super nice.

Comment: Looking at your comment activity on SO, you are pretty hostile in some cases.

Comment: Being upset is never an excuse for being rude or insulting. Everyone can be rude and insulting when they are upset. And they do. Show us that you are different, that you *do* deserve to have your suspension reversed. *Show us*. After all, actions speak louder than words, and right now, you aren't coming off any different than any other user who's mad that they met the consequences of their actions.

Comment: I would suggest you delete this question, take a break for 2 days, and try again. This will most certainly **not** help your case

Comment: In those two months you've been there, you've been contacted *five times* by three different moderators about your behavior. Hard to argue this anything but well-deserved.

Comment: As for your comments to others, as usual, there is an appropriate XKCD for this: https://xkcd.com/438/ It is a good one to keep in mind before you press the "submit" button next to any comment.

Comment: I so disagree with should be closed as site specific.  There should be a review process from an independent panel.  A user should be given reason(s) for the suspension and a one time response with the option for an independent review.  You can have a bad set of mods.

Answer (score 28):

Being able to deal with punishments, even those perceived as unjust, with calm and grace is a generally useful and effective skill.

The correct approach is to realize that the person who suspended you did so for reasons that they believe are valid, and to express your disagreement in a calm and open-minded way, realizing that you *may* still be in the wrong (and that it is OK to be in the wrong; it happens).

One way to appeal a suspension that you believe is incorrect is to clearly and maturely state your case [to the team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140394/230261) in private, and move on from there. There is some related information [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160250/230261).

I *strongly* recommend that you wait a few days before sending off an email to the team. There is no real urgency here, and it will be to your benefit to cool down some. You will be able to make a stronger case if you do.

Comment: Mod messages can't be answered until the eternity, as I can remember only some days long. I think the best is to think at least some hours (ideally, until next morning), and then try to formulate a possible most convincing appeal with many refs. But it probably won't work, because typically not all the reasons of the mod to suspend is communicated in the suspension message. And against the not communicated reasons, you also can't argument.