# You can see the reputation of blocked users with the profile page reputation graph, but the privs are correct

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page, account-suspension, reputation-graph

As this image shows, the user "has" 1 rep, because they're blocked.

> [image]

The profile page reputation graph clearly shows the amount this user actually has, at 1,766.

I think that if the reputation is being zeroed, the graph should either be hidden, or also be zeroed.

Interestingly the privileges are correct (saying meta is next).

Comment: Well, that's because the reputation isn't *really* 1, just displayed as 1 for the duration of the suspension. Not sure we can call this a bug.

Comment: What damage does this cause? I find it handy as a way to see what the user's actual reputation was. Displaying it as "1" everywhere else is perfectly effective enough. If it were hidden I'd probably just make a request for a feature to let you find out the normal rep of a suspended user.

Comment: @JasonC no damage, but there is a reason they set it to 1 so...

Comment: @ShadowWizard I know, perhaps it's not a bug. Feature request perhaps.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256580/how-do-i-appeal-a-suspension-on-stack-overflow was the user btw/