# Is there a way to contact the inventors of this site directly about specific questions?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Contacting Stack Overflow team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140391/contacting-stack-overflow-team)

I have some specific questions that I would like to ask the inventors of this site, and I was wondering how I can contact them. I'm going to list the questions in case I am not allowed to have their e-mail address and someone could possibly answer them on here.

- What is the major language of the website?
- How did they learn this language
- When did they start programming?
- What is their actual job title?
- Do they have a side job?
- How did they get started in the business of web design?
- How did they come up with the idea for stack overflow?
- Did they go to school? If so where?
- Are they considered web designers?
- Is this what I should expect if I want to become a web designer?

So can someone give me an e-mail address, or possibly the answer to some of these questions?

I hope I posted this on the right site. This doesn't seem like it fits anywhere but here.

I realize that there is a Contact Us link at the bottom, but that is too broad for me too send anybody any questions about like this.

Comment: Down votes on this?  Really?  Come on people, you're better than that.  Or at least you should be.

Comment: @ChrisGerken: I't because we disagree. [Votes are different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: @Manishearth: You disagree with what? The PO wants to know how to contact the developers of the site.  Are you their legal guardian and can say who can and can not contact them? Or are you saying the PO really doesn't want to contact the owners of the site?

Comment: @ChrisGerken It is a bad question with no research effort.

Comment: @Chris: "*You disagree with what?*" That he should want to contact the developers and waste their time with irrelevant minutiae.

Comment: I tend to agree with Chris re tone. This is a 16 years old guy trying to decide on a career. Does that really need 9 downvotes? Why not just give him the necessary info (ideally, a link to an overview of the various professional roles involving building web sites)  and be done with it?

Comment: @ChrisGerken: Oh, sorry, I thought you were the OP. We get a lot of people complaining about downvotes on meta, till they realize that they don't mean the same. Seeing the first question, I thought the OP wanted to contact the devs/etc for site-related stuff (which can be answered on meta), and I saw the common "why downvote this" comment, so I replied. Sorry about that :s

Comment: Some of these questions are already answered here, on Meta. Some of them are answered on the founders' respective websites, blogs, etc. You can probably even find email addresses if you poke around a bit. But *generally-speaking*, if you need to get in touch with someone at SE, use the link in the footer. I guarantee you'll get an answer from *someone* here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can contact the team behind the site using the **Contact Us** link displayed prominently on the footer of every page: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/other/. Some of your questions are already answered though.

> What is the major language of the website?

See: [Which tools and technologies are used to build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

> What is their actual job title?

The site is built by a *team* of people. You can see their titles here: https://stackexchange.com/about/team.

> How did they come up with the idea for stack overflow? (etc.)

The *founders* of the site - the duo that started it all, is [Joel Spolsky](http://joelonsoftware.com/) and [Jeff Atwood](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/). They are both prominent bloggers, and if you look hard enough through their blog's backlog you should find a lot of information about how the site (and company) was started.

As others have mentioned, the questions are very wide in scope, so perhaps you might want to state the *purpose* of your research such that the answers can be narrowed down enough that they could actually answer them.

Answer (score 4):

The two founders of Stack overflow both have personal sites that probably contain quite a bit of this information on their "about me" pages. You're basically asking them to write a book here; a few of those are very broad and open questions. Try browsing their pages to see if some of your questions are already answered.

- [About **Jeff Atwood**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/02/about-me.html)
- [About **Joel Spolsky**](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/AboutMe.html)

Answer (score 2):

The contact information you're looking for is included on every page at the bottom labeled "[contact us](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help)."

That said, many of your questions can be answered via publicly available information:

- [This page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network) gives a quick description of the technology underlying Stack Exchange.
- [**Joel Spolsky**](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/) and [**Jeff Atwood**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/) were the founders of Stack Overflow.  They both maintain blogs the archives of which can answer more of your questions.

Questions that aren't answered via the above might need to be motivated a bit better if you hope for a response.  Are you writing a report?  Considering a career change?  Conducting research?

Comment: I am deciding what to be. If something like this could be from a web designer, then that sounds like a promising career

Comment: @CodyGuldner If you want to be a web designer, then you should enjoy web designing.  You should not want to be a web desinger because SO exists, or someone made this site. At best this should be something to motivate you, not the basis of a career.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I have always enjoyed web designing I've just been stuck between 2 careers for a very long time now. So I'm just trying to find small things that are good about each career

Comment: @Cody Stack Overflow is a big product, and it took the work of web designers as well as web developers. Are you looking for a better understanding of what each role does?

Comment: @CodyGuldner We have both designers (well, *a* designer right now) and developers. We're hiring for both positions, so for comparison, here's the [designer job posting](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/24481/product-designer-stack-exchange) and the [developer job posting](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/28723/web-developer-stack-exchange-stack-exchange). As you can see, the tasks and requirements are quite different. Hope this helps.