# Forgot email I signed up with! How can I login with username?

Tags: support, login

I'm sorry for such a stupid question but I recently cleared all my saved login info on Google Chrome. My Stack Overflow login details was there and now I cannot access my account as I am not sure which email I registered the account with.  This is rodit btw.

Is there any way I can login with my username as I do remember my password.

Comment: You were signed up with a Stack Exchange account, or another OpenID provider? And what is the account you lost access to?

Comment: You can't, because your OpenID provider doesn't know your username. (Also, usernames aren't unique.)

Comment: I lost access to 'rodit' but not this one, to one with a trollface as the profile picture... I'm pretty sure it was a stack exchange account...

Comment: Here is one of my original posts:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20722386/reading-large-files-into-memory

Comment: Perhaps it's then best to use the contact form to contact the team. Then you can share any possible personally identifying information, rather than doing so here in public.

Comment: Ill try that now... Thanks Bart

Comment: How do I do that bart?

Comment: @rodit http://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact

Comment: Or see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140391/contacting-stack-overflow-team/140395#140395) question

Comment: I see the other account is now deleted? What happened?